# R: accessing cells in a data frame

Tags: r

`df1` and `df2` are two dataframes (code below).

```
> df1
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  6  7  8  9 10
3 11 12 13 14 15

> df2
   row col  drop
1    1   1 FALSE
2    2   1 FALSE
3    3   1  TRUE
4    1   2 FALSE
5    2   2 FALSE
6    3   2 FALSE
7    1   3  TRUE
8    2   3 FALSE
9    3   3 FALSE
10   1   4 FALSE
11   2   4 FALSE
12   3   4 FALSE
13   1   5 FALSE
14   2   5 FALSE
15   3   5 FALSE
```

Using the information from `df2`, I would like to transform `df1` into

```
> df1
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  NA  4  5
2  6  7  8  9 10
3 NA  12 13 14 15
```

How would you do this?

---

**Code to create `df1` and `df2`:**

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:15, nrow = 3, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE))
df2 <- expand.grid(row = 1:3, col = 1:5) %>%
  mutate(drop = c(rep(FALSE, 2), TRUE, rep(FALSE, 3), TRUE, rep(FALSE, 8)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset only `TRUE` values from `df2`, convert it into matrix and assign `NA` to those row and column indices in `df1`.

```
df1[as.matrix(df2[df2$drop, -3])] <- NA

df1
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  2 NA  4  5
#2  6  7  8  9 10
#3 NA 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 1):

As we are using `dplyr`, we can make use of the chain

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    filter(drop) %>% 
    select(-drop) %>%
    as.matrix %>% 
    replace(df1, ., NA)
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  2 NA  4  5
#2  6  7  8  9 10
#3 NA 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: @user7064  Yes, the characters from `%>%` and the line split into different lines (for easier understanding)